# Can't understand why I'm getting this nullReference exception in ASP MVC when loading a page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, nullreferenceexception

I have a web application that is not giving me any problems on my computer, but when I deploy it to the server I get this error. It doesn't give me any source code lines to check and I don't have any idea why it may be happening

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a9dc635c\ccb3814\App_Web_item.cshtml.f0356b3c.uyw8roer.0.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page__AssemblyResource_MyProject_Web_Mvc__Version_1_0_0_0__Culture_neutral__PublicKeyToken_null_Views_LeagueGlobal_Item_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a9dc635c\ccb3814\App_Web_item.cshtml.f0356b3c.uyw8roer.0.cs:0
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +195
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +383
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +32
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +977396
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +977396
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +964636
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: Could you add the code for App_Web_item.cshtml?

Comment: have you tried delete the temp files referenced in the error message?

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same issue. Unfortunately the stack trace isn't very helpful in this case. The exception is happening for sure in the view, what it was in my case:

```
@Model.SomeProperty.Trim()
```

And Model.SomeProperty was null. As there is no way how to debug it; I recommend binary split approach:

- save your view somewhere else
- remove one-by-one logical parts from your view
- after each removal save your view and retest
- if the exception is no longer reproducible, the NullReferenceException happened in the block you've removed; so add it back and remove logical parts inside this block until you isolate the line causing an exception

Its lame I know, but I found no other way - btw. this is what I got for doing controller job in view.

Comment: Funny, I was doing this kind of 'rem and refresh' troubleshooting a null ref at a code line that was quite far away from the eventual problem, when I got the "No relevant source lines" message. I can confirm that this approach does end up finding your null.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **line 0** of your source file at:

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a9dc635c\ccb3814\App_Web_item.cshtml.f0356b3c.uyw8roer.0.cs

Then, use this to pin-point where exactly the exception happens in your code block:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch (NullReferenceException ex)
{
      ShowMessageBox("Error" + ex.Message);
}
```

Check that:

1. You've initiated the variables that you're manipulating.
2. Variables that you're using have not become **null** since deploying it to the server.
3. You are not using variables outside of your scope.